# Why C# take the function with double type instead of the int type?

Tags: c#, function, integer, double

The problem is, that when I run this code:

```
    class Animal
    {
        public void WriteMessage(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message from Animal");
        }
    }

    class Bull : Animal
    {
        public void WriteMessage(double p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message from Bull");
        }
    }
```

---

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 5;
        Bull b = new Bull();
        b.WriteMessage(i);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Then I get the output:
`Message from Bull` (Why?)

But, when I swap arguments in functions like this:

```
    class Animal
    {
        public void WriteMessage(double i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message from Animal");
        }
    }

    class Bull : Animal
    {
        public void WriteMessage(int p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message from Bull");
        }
    }
```

And change the passed type to double:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double i = 5;
    Bull b = new Bull();
    b.WriteMessage(i);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Then the output is:
`Message from Animal`

Visual Studio shows, that there are two overloads for this function, one with int and the second with double. Still when the code runs, in both cases the function with double type argument is being run.

I would be very happy to know why it works like that. Thanks.

Comment: Compare: `int i = 0;
double d = 1d;
d = i;
i = d;`

Comment: Because `Bull` is considered for overload resolution before `Animal`, so if the `double` overload exists it will be matched. But in the second case, the `int` overload cannot match, so overload resolution moves on to the base type `Animal`

Comment: That's just how the overload resolution rules work. There's an implicit conversion from `int` to `double`, but not from `double` to `int`. So when using the `Bull` type, both methods qualify. And the method in the more-derived class is considered a better option, so it's chosen. See duplicate.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I don't think the fact that `Animal/int` qualifies is relevant in that case, it's not even looked at, overload resolution looks always looks at derived classes first

Comment: @Charlieface: _"it's not even looked at"_ -- I don't think that's strictly true. It's true that the methods in the base class are removed early in the process, but they do start out in the list of considered methods. See e.g. [_"in other words, the overload resolution algorithm starts by searching the class for an applicable method. If it finds one then all the other **applicable methods in deeper base classes are removed from the candidate set** for overload resolution"_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/future-breaking-changes-part-three).

Comment: Because Bull is an Animal, so it can call Animal's methods. If you pass 'int i' to the 'b.WriteMessage(i)' method it will call the method from Bull, but if you pass a 'double i', since there is no 'WriteMessage' method in Bull which takes double, the method from the parent class, Animal, is called.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You're quite right, [C# language spec bullet point 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#member-lookup)